# ASM 8086 divide by 0

Tags: assembly

I am trying to solve a problem that reads a real number from the keyboard, adds pi to it and then it writes it in a file. Everything works great until I get to a div and I get Divide by 0 error. Here it is the part of code with the problem:

```
mov ax, frac
div ten
```

frac is a word like 234f, I ran it through turbo debugger and ax gets the value 234f, ten is defined in the data segment as a byte like this

```
ten db 10
```

In turbo debugger, when I get here, in div 10, it takes me into the internal structure of the div function and eventually sends the Divided by 0 error.

I have to mention that right before that I did another div, exactly the same on another variable and everything went perfect.
Are there anyother implications to the div function that I don't know about? I can post all the code if necessary but it's long and I don't know if you would understand it.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes me into the internal structure of the div function"? `div` is not a function. Its a processor instruction. Its not stored in memory. Its silk screened directly onto the CPU chip.

Comment: Paste the code for `div` function

Comment: My bad, Ishould've mentioned I'm new to assembly. It takes me in some internal code ( I didn't write it ) where it does push ax, mov al, 12 nop push cs... Some piece of code about the div, I don't know but it does this after the "div ten"

Comment: It takes me here: http://postimg.org/image/yydvto5bp/ (I'm not sure if I can post pictures here)

Comment: @Melph7 -- Send a screen shot of the line thats executing right before the `push ax`

Comment: Here it is: http://postimg.org/image/d5bxu2obr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually getting an overflow, not a division by zero (but it's the same exception).
The problem is your division produces a 8 bit result, and your input is `AX=375Fh=18271` which when divided by `10` gives `1827` and that does not fit into 8 bits. (That's from your screenshot, but it's similar for `AX=234F` as well.)

If you need 16 bit result, you will have to use the 32 bit division. Take care to zero-extend your input and divisor. Example:

```
xor dx, dx ; zero extend ax
div ten    ; divide dx:ax by ten (use word override if necessary)
; quotient now in ax, remainder in dx
...
ten dw 10  ; notice it is a word
```

Consult the instruction set reference about how the various forms of `div` work.